# Should I use a Dashboard for a mobile website

Tags: website-design, gui-design, mobile, dashboard

Should I use a Dashboard, in the style of an app, for the mobile version of a website? Is it considered a good or bad practice?

There is some images associated with the news feed on the home pages of this website, so it slow down the loading page a bit (but not much, since I send resized images to mobile user).

What do you think?

Comment: Using or not using a dashboard is not good or bad practice. Implementing it following good design principles (and breaking rules when required) or not makes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a dashboard only if the content of your website frequently changes over time. Using a dashboard also means that you drastically limit the amount of information presented to the user.

Do you want the mobile site to be an additional feature (in this case, a dashboard can be a good idea), or as close as possible to the original site?

You should ask yourself "Do I need a dashboard ?" and, as said before, it depends on the type of website.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the obvious cop-out answer, but it entirely depends on the type of site it is and what users are trying to do on it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This c/should have been a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Philip, can you give us some more details?

I would like to add though that if by using a dashboard for a mobile version of a website the look of the mobile website dramatically changes from the way the large screen version looks you will end up with visual inconsistency and users will have to re-learn the layout of the website which could be bad.

Answer (score 0):

1: Should I use a Dashboard?

Yes you can use dashboard but be care full about images and visualization, the mobile screen is comparatively small as PC/MAC. As We have developed a site where we are using only two graphs which is displayed just after the header(20px height , width 100% each) , we use only 1px red and green repeated images.

2: There is some images associated with the news feed on the home pages of this website?

You can use sprites to minimize number of request to the server; this will boost your performance.
Below the header graphs we are displaying 5 Li (Orders delivered 5/10, Order picked 10/100)  etc, these LI(Area) is decorated with corresponding images.

3: There is some images associated with the news feed on the home pages of this website, so it slow down the loading page?

You can view this demo for pre loading images and sprites
[JqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home)